# SMD diode(?) identification

Tags: diodes, identification, surface-mount

I've been searching for a while to find this part but my Google searching and datasheet surfing hasn't gotten me anywhere.

I'm pretty sure this is a Schottky diode in a SOD-523 package but I haven't been able to find anything with these markings on it.

[image: Small SMD diode circled in red]

I figured I'd post here to see if anyone had any hints on where to look.

Comment: Nice magnified picture!

Comment: Thanks! It took many shots with my phone and a jewelers loupe haha

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After investigation it looks like [RB751S-40](https://pl.aliexpress.com/item/32913023471.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.main.1.392ed48esYlTKR&algo_pvid=c85d1301-3845-40b3-bfaa-5c935fdfc289&algo_exp_id=c85d1301-3845-40b3-bfaa-5c935fdfc289-0&pdp_ext_f=%7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2265926261295%22%7D&pdp_npi=2%40dis%21PLN%2111.38%2111.16%21%21%21%21%21%40211bf48d16738506951662740d06b6%2165926261295%21sea&curPageLogUid=P9E6mCYuiLU6)

[image]

Comment: Here's a [more reputable supplier](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/onsemi/RB751S40T1G?qs=sGAEpiMZZMtbRapU8LlZDwOXpTTbNuB%2FOaoit%252BU3kjs%3D).

Comment: Wow that's awesome! Thanks so much. What search terms did you use to find this? I'd mainly like to know in order to upskill myself for future parts searching!